# The difference results about difflib in python

Tags: python

I'm novice in python.Now I'm learning difflib in python.I want to know why

```
for x in difflib.Differ().compare([1,2,3],[0,2,1]):
    print x
```

result:

```
+ 0
+ 2
  1
- 2
- 3
```

why not :

```
+ 0
  2
  1
```

Comment: Order in lists matters, so it looks good - second list in comparison to first has two additional items on beginning and is missing 2 items on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difflib respects the ordering of arguments.  It essentially shows the edits that would transform one sequence into another.

When you don't care about order, a set difference may be what you want:

```
>>> {1, 2, 3} - {0, 2, 1}
set([3])
>>> {0, 2, 1} - {1, 2, 3}
set([0])
```